# how to output the Stanford Parser SemanticGraph as a numeric list of nodes and edges

Tags: java, matrix, graph, stanford-nlp

Please help me encode the Stanford Parser SemanticGraph output as a numeric list of nodes and edges 
where Nodes have IDs and labels, edges consist of two node ids and an edge weight like: 
Node List: 1  A , 2  B... Edge list: 1 2 10, 2 1 10.
Though, according to the stanford nlp javadoc -->Class SemanticGraph:

> There is no mechanism for returning all edges  at once (eg
>   `edgeSet()`). This is intentional. Use `edgeIterable()` to iterate over
>   the edges if necessary.

Hence, I tried to use a similar example with a suggestion from one of the forum members but didn't get it working.
I'm using Eclipse Luna.
There is my attempt:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

public class StanfordCoreNlpDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out;
        if (args.length > 1) {
            out = new PrintWriter(args[1]);
        } else {
           out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        }

        PrintWriter xmlOut = null;
        if (args.length > 2) {
            xmlOut = new PrintWriter(args[2]);
        }

        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP();
        Annotation annotation;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            annotation = new Annotation(IOUtils.slurpFileNoExceptions(args[0]));
        } else {
            annotation = new Annotation("Out of the unconstructed nature ...");    
        }

        pipeline.annotate(annotation);
        pipeline.prettyPrint(annotation, out);
        if (xmlOut != null) {
            pipeline.xmlPrint(annotation, xmlOut);
        }

        // An Annotation is a Map and you can get and use the various analyses individually.
        // For instance, this gets the parse tree of the first sentence in the text.
        List<CoreMap> sentences =  annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
        if (sentences != null && sentences.size() > 0) {
            CoreMap sentence = sentences.get(0);
            Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
            out.println();
            out.println("The first sentence parsed is:");
            tree.pennPrint(out);
            SemanticGraph sg = sg.get(StanfordCoreNlpSemGraph.class);
            for (SemanticGraphEdge edge : sg.getEdgesIterable()) {
                int headIndex = edge.getGovernor().index();
                int depIndex = edge.getDependent().index();
                int weight = 1 // Not sure what "edge weight" if at all put here?
                System.out.printf("%d %d %d%n", headIndex, depIndex, weight);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting following two errors:

```
SemanticGraph cannot be resolved to a type --> SemanticGraph sg = sg.get(StanfordCoreNlpSemGraph.class); 
SemanticGraphEdge cannot be resolved to a type --> for (SemanticGraphEdge edge : sg.getEdgesIterable())
```

Also, I need the nodes list which might beobtained by iterating over the tokens in the sentence and printing them out. 
But again, I’m not sure how to implement it.
Many thanks by advance for
 your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to get the semantic graph instance from itself?

It seems to me that you should be getting the SemanticGraph from the sentence, using :

```
SemanticGraph sg = sentence.get(SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.BasicDependenciesAnnotation.class);
```